# Beautiful soup scraper find text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.9

```
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
     from lxml import etree
     import requests
     import re
     URL = "https://csimarket.com/stocks/at_glance.php?code=AA"

     HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36', \
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

     webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
     dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
     raw_html = soup.find('a', href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100")
     print(raw_html)
```

I am getting:

```
\<span class="oran2"\>•\</span\>Basic Materials
```

I just want to "Basic Materials" how do i do that?

I am doing:

```
raw_html = soup.find('a', href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100")
```

I want to find `../Industry/Industry_Data.php` only. Thanks

Comment: To keep focus there should be just one issue per question @Rohit Patil answerd the main issue - It is not clear what *I want to find ../Industry/Industry_Data.php only* means.. So if it is an additional issue it would be predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with excat this focus. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do

`raw_html = soup.find('a', href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100")`

you get the whole tag as the result of the function. Currently it contains the Text and also a span that has a bullet point character.

So to get just the text ("Basic Materials"), you'll need to remove the span from the element. you can do this by using `.decompose()` on the span(or any element that you want to remove in general).

After that you can use the `.text` attribute to get the inner text of the `a` tag.

PS: the `.text` contains whitespace so doing a `.strip()` is recommended.

code:

```py
span = a_tag.find("span")
span.decompose()
print(a_tag.text.strip())
```

output:

```
Basic Materials
```